# Adding text search to content based image retrieval (convnet)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I've implemented CBIR app by using standard ConvNet approach:

1. Use Transfer Learning to extract features from the data set of images
2. Cluster extracted features via knn
3. Given search image, extract its features
4. Give top 10 images that are close to the image in hand in knn network

I am getting good results, but I want to further improve them by adding text search as well. For instance, when my image is the steering wheel of the car, the close results will be any circular objects that resemble a steering wheel for instance bike wheel. What would be the best possible way to input text say "car part" to produce only steering wheels similar to the search image.

I am unable to find a good way to combine ConvNet with text search model to construct improved knn network.

My other idea is to use ElasticSearch in order to do text search, something that ElasticSearch is good at. For instance, I would do a CBIR search described previously and out of the return results, I can look up their description and then use ElasticSearch on the subset of the hits to produce the results. Maybe tag images with classes and allow user to de/select groups of images of interest.

I don't want to do text search before image search as some of the images are poorly described so text search would miss them.

Any thoughts or ideas will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have not found the original paper, but maybe you might find it interesting: https://www.slideshare.net/xavigiro/multimodal-deep-learning-d4l4-deep-learning-for-speech-and-language-upc-2017

It is about looking for a vector space where both images and text are (multimodal embedding). In this way you can find text similar to a images, images referring to a text, or use the tuple text / image to find similar images.

I think maybe this idea is an interesting point to start from.

Comment: Thank you for the link! I will have to review some of the mentioned research to see if I can make it work for my problem. From the first glance, I might be able to tune Visual and Textual Question Answering approach for my purpose... we shall see. :)